# How to move onclick code to one place using something like class. Repeated code at various html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
onclick="triggersTracking($(this).attr('a'),$(this).attr('b'),$(this).attr('c'),Enum.BtnSellerView)"
```

I have this line at various HTML tags/buttons. I want to move this code to one place for better maintainability. The problem is with third/last attribute i am passing since its Enum, it has different values being passed from different tag elements.

How can i move it to one common place where it would get invoke. For example I could have made a class if i have had just these (this).attr since its common for every tag.

Comment: show us the html and the functions

Comment: <p onclick="triggersTracking($(this).attr('a'),$(this).attr('b'),$(this).attr('c'),Enum.pClick)"

<h2
onclick="triggersTracking($(this).attr('a'),$(this).attr('b'),$(this).attr('c'),Enum.h2Click)"

triggersTracking = function(a, b, c, enumType)
{
}

i want to remove these multiple triggersTracking from various tag elements. The only problem is how do i pass enum.

Comment: see my answer and let me know if you want any help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like

1. Give all the elements a common class name
2. Then add a data attribute, "data-enum" to each tag with corresponding value.

Then you can write the code like this,

```
$(".className").click(function () {
    var a = $(this).attr('a');
    var b = $(this).attr('b');
    var c = $(this).attr('c');
    var enum = $(this).data('enum');
});
```

Comment: data-enum is passing string and i am unable to convert it to corresponding int.

I tried this data-enum=parseInt(listingsTrackingCategoryEnum.BtnSellerView) but didn't work. Can you help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to get this:

```
$("body").on("click", "someClass", function() {
    //code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to write `$(this).attr('a'),$(this).attr('b'),$(this).attr('c')`

again and agin on every onclick just paas `this` object and get them all in function like :

```
onclick="triggersTracking(this,Enum.BtnSellerView)"


function triggersTracking(obj,enumVal){
  // get these values here by obj (no repetitive code needed in every onclick ) 
   $(obj).attr('a')
   $(obj).attr('c')
   $(obj).attr('b')

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do some thing like this**

[**.click()**](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

[**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[**.data()**](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

> if you use attributes like data-enum , data-e....
>
> so use $(this).data() it will return all attributes in JSON which is starting
>   from data-

```js
$('.click').click(function(e) {

  console.log($(this).data())
  $('body').append($(this).attr('a'))

})

// if you have dynamic html tag then go for .on 

$('body').on('click','.click',function(){
//callback 
  console.log($(this).data())
  $('body').append($(this).attr('a'))

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="click" a="i am a attr of  p" b="i am b" data-a="i am data a">i am p</p>
<h2 class="click" a="i am a attr of h2">i am  h2</h2>
```